# Splitting a column into new column based on condition

Tags: r

This is my data-frame to make it simple I will show only 3 column
**Objective**

I would like to split the dataframe my 3rd column into a new column with new name "`direction`"

```
dput(head(c))
structure(list(Chemical.Name = c("Ethylnitrosourea", "Valproic Acid", 
"sodium arsenite", "Tobacco Smoke Pollution", "Valproic Acid", 
"Valproic Acid"), Gene.Symbol = c("A", "A1BG", "A1CF", "A2M", 
"A2M", "A2M-AS1"), Interaction.Actions = c("increases^mutagenesis", 
"affects^expression", "decreases^expression", "decreases^expression", 
"decreases^expression", "decreases^expression")), row.names = c(1L, 
8L, 13L, 36L, 42L, 44L), class = "data.frame")
```

My data frame looks like this

```
 head(c)
             Chemical.Name Gene.Symbol   Interaction.Actions
1         Ethylnitrosourea           A increases^mutagenesis
8            Valproic Acid        A1BG    affects^expression
13         sodium arsenite        A1CF  decreases^expression
36 Tobacco Smoke Pollution         A2M  decreases^expression
42           Valproic Acid         A2M  decreases^expression
44           Valproic Acid     A2M-AS1  decreases^expression
```

So here I would like to parse the 4th column in my dataframe called `c` and then make a new `df` or add new `column` to it where the new column can be called `direction`which should contain term  that is coming before `^` word or anything that is on the left side of this `^` which will go to the a new column under direction.

I would like to dput my patterns that exist in that third column

```
[1] "increases^mutagenesis"                                                           
  [2] "affects^expression"                                                              
  [3] "decreases^expression"                                                            
  [4] "increases^expression"                                                            
  [5] "increases^transport"                                                             
  [6] "increases^export"                                                                
  [7] "affects^binding|increases^activity|increases^expression"                         
  [8] "decreases^response to substance"                                                 
  [9] "decreases^uptake"                                                                
 [10] "decreases^reaction|decreases^uptake"                                             
 [11] "increases^activity"                                                              
 [12] "decreases^reaction|decreases^response to substance"                              
 [13] "affects^response to substance"                                                   
 [14] "decreases^reaction|increases^export"                                             
 [15] "decreases^activity"                                                              
 [16] "decreases^methylation"                                                           
 [17] "decreases^reaction|increases^transport"                                          
 [18] "decreases^reaction|increases^activity"                                           
 [19] "decreases^reaction|increases^uptake"                                             
 [20] "affects^binding|decreases^activity"                                              
 [21] "affects^transport|increases^reaction"                                            
 [22] "increases^secretion"                                                             
 [23] "decreases^reaction|increases^expression"                                         
 [24] "affects^transport"                                                               
 [25] "affects^metabolic processing"                                                    
 [26] "affects^export"                                                                  
 [27] "affects^binding"                                                                 
 [28] "decreases^phosphorylation"                                                       
 [29] "decreases^reaction|increases^phosphorylation"                                    
 [30] "increases^phosphorylation"                                                       
 [31] "decreases^activity|decreases^reaction"                                           
 [32] "affects^reaction|increases^expression"                                           
 [33] "affects^cotreatment|decreases^reaction|increases^expression"                     
 [34] "increases^methylation"                                                           
 [35] "affects^cotreatment|increases^expression|increases^secretion"                    
 [36] "affects^cotreatment|increases^expression"                                        
 [37] "affects^binding|increases^reaction"                                              
 [38] "affects^methylation"                                                             
 [39] "decreases^reaction|increases^abundance"                                          
 [40] "decreases^expression|decreases^reaction"                                         
 [41] "affects^binding|decreases^reaction"                                              
 [42] "affects^localization|decreases^reaction"                                         
 [43] "affects^binding|decreases^reaction|increases^reaction"                           
 [44] "increases^response to substance"                                                 
 [45] "affects^localization"                                                            
 [46] "increases^reduction"                                                             
 [47] "increases^metabolic processing"                                                  
 [48] "increases^phosphorylation|increases^reaction"                                    
 [49] "decreases^phosphorylation|decreases^reaction"                                    
 [50] "decreases^phosphorylation|increases^reaction"                                    
 [51] "decreases^activity|decreases^phosphorylation"                                    
 [52] "increases^activity|increases^phosphorylation"                                    
 [53] "increases^abundance|increases^phosphorylation"                                   
 [54] "affects^cotreatment|increases^abundance|increases^phosphorylation"               
 [55] "decreases^expression|decreases^phosphorylation"                                  
 [56] "increases^expression|increases^phosphorylation"                                  
 [57] "affects^phosphorylation"                                                         
 [58] "decreases^expression|increases^abundance"                                        
 [59] "decreases^reaction|increases^activity|increases^phosphorylation"                 
 [60] "decreases^phosphorylation|increases^abundance"                                   
 [61] "affects^cotreatment|decreases^activity"                                          
 [62] "affects^binding|decreases^reaction|increases^expression"                         
 [63] "increases^chemical synthesis"                                                    
 [64] "decreases^response to substance|increases^mutagenesis"                           
 [65] "increases^expression|increases^secretion"                                        
 [66] "increases^expression|increases^reaction"                                         
 [67] "increases^abundance"                                                             
 [68] "affects^binding|increases^degradation"                                           
 [69] "increases^uptake"                                                                
 [70] "affects^binding|increases^methylation"                                           
 [71] "increases^abundance|increases^expression"                                        
 [72] "increases^activity|increases^localization"                                       
 [73] "affects^localization|increases^expression"                                       
 [74] "decreases^reaction|increases^expression|increases^reaction"                      
 [75] "increases^cleavage"                                                              
 [76] "affects^cotreatment|decreases^expression"                                        
 [77] "affects^expression|increases^abundance"                                          
 [78] "decreases^expression|increases^abundance|increases^reaction"                     
 [79] "affects^cotreatment|decreases^expression|decreases^reaction"                     
 [80] "affects^expression|affects^reaction"                                             
 [81] "increases^activity|increases^cleavage"                                           
 [82] "affects^cotreatment|decreases^response to substance"                             
 [83] "decreases^expression|increases^reaction"                                         
 [84] "decreases^reaction|increases^methylation"                                        
 [85] "decreases^reaction|increases^abundance|increases^activity|increases^localization"
 [86] "decreases^reaction|increases^cleavage"                                           
 [87] "increases^cleavage|increases^expression"                                         
 [88] "increases^activity|increases^expression"                                         
 [89] "increases^activity|increases^reaction"                                           
 [90] "affects^cotreatment|increases^cleavage"                                          
 [91] "affects^cotreatment|increases^activity"                                          
 [92] "affects^cotreatment|decreases^reaction|increases^activity"                       
 [93] "decreases^reaction|increases^activity|increases^reaction"                        
 [94] "decreases^activity|increases^reaction"                                           
 [95] "affects^activity"                                                                
 [96] "affects^activity|increases^abundance"                                            
 [97] "decreases^activity|increases^abundance"                                          
 [98] "affects^activity|affects^cotreatment"                                            
 [99] "affects^cotreatment|decreases^activity|decreases^reaction"                       
[100] "decreases^reaction|increases^secretion"                                          
[101] "decreases^secretion"                                                             
[102] "affects^localization|decreases^reaction|increases^expression"                    
[103] "affects^expression|affects^methylation"                                          
[104] "decreases^expression|increases^phosphorylation"                                  
[105] "decreases^activity|increases^phosphorylation"                                    
[106] "decreases^methylation|increases^expression"                                      
[107] "affects^cotreatment|increases^expression|increases^reaction"                     
[108] "affects^cotreatment|increases^expression|increases^phosphorylation"              
[109] "increases^activity|increases^hydrolysis"                                         
[110] "increases^hydrolysis"                                                            
[111] "affects^binding|increases^expression"                                            
[112] "affects^binding|increases^activity"                                              
[113] "increases^stability"                                                             
[114] "affects^chemical synthesis"                                                      
[115] "decreases^reaction|increases^activity|increases^expression"                      
[116] "increases^degradation"                                                           
[117] "increases^chemical synthesis|increases^metabolic processing"                     
[118] "increases^chemical synthesis|increases^hydroxylation"                            
[119] "increases^hydroxylation"                                                         
[120] "increases^abundance|increases^metabolic processing"                              
[121] "increases^oxidation"                                                             
[122] "affects^cotreatment|decreases^expression|increases^activity"                     
[123] "affects^cotreatment|affects^response to substance"                               
[124] "decreases^abundance"                                                             
[125] "decreases^abundance|decreases^expression"                                        
[126] "decreases^abundance|increases^secretion"                                         
[127] "increases^abundance|increases^activity"                                          
[128] "affects^cotreatment|increases^phosphorylation"                                   
[129] "affects^metabolic processing|affects^response to substance"                      
[130] "increases^acetylation"                                                           
[131] "affects^binding|decreases^abundance|increases^activity"                          
[132] "decreases^hydroxylation"                                                         
[133] "decreases^reaction|increases^stability"                                          
[134] "decreases^abundance|increases^expression"                                        
[135] "affects^cotreatment|decreases^reaction|increases^abundance"                      
[136] "affects^cotreatment|increases^abundance"                                         
[137] "affects^cotreatment|increases^secretion"                                         
[138] "affects^cotreatment|increases^chemical synthesis"                                
[139] "affects^cotreatment|affects^localization"                                        
[140] "increases^chemical synthesis|increases^expression"                               
[141] "affects^secretion"                                                               
[142] "increases^reaction|increases^secretion"                                          
[143] "decreases^reaction|increases^degradation"                                        
[144] "affects^cotreatment|affects^expression"                                          
[145] "decreases^expression|decreases^secretion"                                        
[146] "affects^reaction|decreases^expression"                                           
[147] "decreases^reaction|increases^expression|increases^phosphorylation"               
[148] "decreases^localization"                                                          
[149] "affects^binding|decreases^expression"                                            
[150] "increases^lipidation"                                                            
[151] "increases^expression|increases^lipidation"                                       
[152] "affects^cotreatment|increases^activity|increases^phosphorylation"                
[153] "decreases^activity|decreases^expression"                                         
[154] "decreases^reaction|increases^activity|increases^secretion"                       
[155] "decreases^activity|increases^activity"                                           
[156] "increases^expression|increases^localization"                                     
[157] "affects^binding|decreases^reaction|increases^activity"                           
[158] "decreases^degradation"                                                           
[159] "decreases^reaction|increases^chemical synthesis|increases^expression"            
[160] "increases^expression|increases^stability"                                        
[161] "increases^activity|increases^chemical synthesis"                                 
[162] "increases^activity|increases^chemical synthesis|increases^phosphorylation"       
[163] "increases^export|increases^expression"                                           
[164] "increases^localization"                                                          
[165] "affects^binding|affects^localization"                                            
[166] "increases^cleavage|increases^reaction"                                           
[167] "affects^binding|decreases^response to substance"                                 
[168] "decreases^activity|increases^mutagenesis"                                        
[169] "increases^ubiquitination"                                                        
[170] "increases^degradation|increases^reaction"                                        
[171] "increases^sumoylation"                                                           
[172] "affects^abundance"                                                               
[173] "affects^localization|increases^activity"                                         
[174] "affects^activity|affects^binding"                                                
[175] "decreases^acetylation|increases^activity"                                        
[176] "decreases^acetylation"                                                           
[177] "decreases^activity|decreases^chemical synthesis"                                 
[178] "increases^degradation|increases^ubiquitination"                                  
[179] "affects^cotreatment|decreases^phosphorylation"                                   
[180] "decreases^reaction|increases^activity|increases^localization"                    
[181] "decreases^reaction|increases^acetylation"                                        
[182] "decreases^activity|decreases^localization"                                       
[183] "affects^localization|increases^phosphorylation"                                  
[184] "decreases^methylation|increases^reaction"                                        
[185] "decreases^activity|decreases^response to substance"                              
[186] "decreases^reaction|increases^import"                                             
[187] "increases^expression|increases^uptake"                                           
[188] "decreases^reaction|increases^expression|increases^secretion"                     
[189] "increases^activity|increases^cleavage|increases^reaction"                        
[190] "increases^abundance|increases^expression|increases^reaction"                     
[191] "decreases^reaction|increases^acetylation|increases^reaction"                     
[192] "increases^mutagenesis|increases^reaction"                                        
[193] "increases^glucuronidation"                                                       
[194] "affects^splicing"                                                                
[195] "increases^splicing"
```

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated

Comment: that is example i mean the output from my data should be like that data frame ..

Comment: i will remove that part i guess its more confusing

Comment: What output you want for the add column ?

Comment: @Limey let me run that thing ..coincidentally answer give by akrun

Comment: @MohamedDesouky anything that is before this symbol `^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base R` option with `trimws`

```
transform(df1, Interaction.Actions = trimws(Interaction.Actions, 
     whitespace = "\\^.*"))
```

Comment: I used this `c$direction <-  word(c$Interaction.Actions,1,sep = "\\^")`

Answer (score 1):

- Does this help ?

```
c$Interaction.Actions |> gsub("(.*)\\^.*" , "\\1" , x = _)
```

- Output

```
[1] "increases" "affects"   "decreases" "decreases" "decreases"
[6] "decreases"
```

Comment: thank you for the answer new way to solve my problem